Element for accepting cookies
Hi have this bit of code to click a cookies banner accept when present, my issue is when ran on a server that has this banner turned off if doesn't move on if the length is less than 1 say, I would like it to if the element isn't present to just execute the next step in test.
if (Cypress.$(this.LoginElementLocators.LoginPageLocators.cookies_accept).length > 0) {
  cy.get(this.LoginElementLocators.LoginPageLocators.cookies_accept).click()
}  

At the minute the test fails saying it didn't find the element

What does the code in this.LoginElementLocators... look like? It's hard to grasp exactly what you're trying to do without a minimally reproducible code sample.

That is just a json containing all element names on that webpage nothing else eg. cookies_accept = element_name

The syntax you have used is good, so some other possibilities are:
The cookie banner gets hidden rather than removed
If this is the case, the main banner container might have CSS display: none or possibly opacity: 0 if there is a fade animation.
You would adjust the test by adding :visible to the selector, but you wouldn't use the accept button, rather the cookie banner container - for example:
const visibleCookieContainer = `${Locators.cookies_container}:visible`
if (Cypress.$(visibleCookieContainer).length) {    // don't need > 0
  ...

The if() check is happening before the cookie banner container appears
This is less likely since you mention the test fails saying it didn't find the element, which means the if() statement passes and the cy.get() statement fails.
You can try polling for the element as per this answer
const ifElementExists = (selector, attempt = 0) => {
  if (attempt === 100) return null           // wait up to 10 seconds
  if (Cypress.$(selector).length === 0) {
    cy.wait(100, {log:false})                // wait in 100ms chunks
      .then(() => ifElementExists(selector, ++attempt))      
  }
  return cy.get(selector, {log:false})     
}

ifElementExists(Locators.cookies_accept).then($el => {
  if ($el?.length) {  // null or element
    $el.click()
  }
})

The cookie banner container may or may not appear
If the cookie banner appearing is "random", try adding a MutationObserver as per this answer
function handler(win) {
  const selector = Locators.cookies_accept
  const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    const addedElement = mutations?[0].addedNodes?[0]
    if (addedElement?.classList.contains(selector)) {
      addedElement.click()
    }
  }
  observer.observe(win.document.body, { childList: true })
}
cy.on('window:load', handler)

This waits in the background and fires only when the button appears. Because this is a background handler, it may not get the chance to fire, since javascript is single-threaded.
